# `opencv_createsamples` is missing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to train some images using OpenCV. But the issue is, I can't find `opencv_createsamples` program. I installed the OpenCV in the normal way, because I am using Windows 7. Where is this `opencv_createsamples` ? How can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

It should be located under `OpenCV-Dir\build\x64 or x86\vc1x\bin\`.

Comment: Hi, No I have nothing like that.

Comment: @Hope Then you need to download a full version of it. Latest version should be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm. Do you mind giving me the link you are refering? I am in windows 7, normally use the GUI installer. So the latest one got this application?

Comment: Thanks for the relply. You didn't manually build the opencv using cmake right?

Comment: @Hope Yes. You don't need to to get it.